# Apollo query that depends on another query's result

Tags: vue.js, apollo, nuxt.js

I’m trying to create an Apollo query (in Vue/Nuxt) that depends on the result of another query.

`sessions` needs `person` in order to use `this.person.id`. How can I ensure that `person` exists before getting data for `sessions`?

My script and queries are below. Both queries work fine in GraphiQL. Thank you!

### JS

```js
  import gql from 'graphql-tag'
  import Photo from '~/components/Photo.vue'
  import Session from '~/components/Session.vue'
  import {Route} from 'vue-router'
  import { currentPerson, currentPersonSessions } from '~/apollo/queries.js'

  export default {
    name: 'Speaker',
    props: ['slug', 'id', 'person'],
    data() {
      return {
        title: 'Speaker',
        routeParam: this.$route.params.slug
      }
    },
    apollo: {
      person: {
        query: currentPerson,
        loadingKey: 'loading',
        variables() {
          return {
            slug: this.routeParam
          }
        }
      },
      sessions: {
        query: currentPersonSessions,
        loadingKey: 'loading',
        variables() {
          return {
            itemId: this.person.id
          }
        }
      }
    },
    components: {
      Photo,
      Session
    }
  }
```

### Queries

```js
export const currentPerson = gql `query ($slug: String!) {
  person(filter: { slug: { eq: $slug }}) {
    name
    bio
    affiliation
    id
    photo {
      url
    }
  }
}`

export const currentPersonSessions = gql `query($itemId: ItemId!) {
  allSessions (filter: { speakers: { anyIn: [$itemId] }}) {
    title
    slug
    start
    end
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by breaking out the part the sessions into a separate component.

Is that the appropriate way to handle a case like this, or is there a better way by chaining the requests here? If there's a way to do this, I still wouldn't mind hearing other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to have a proper graph of your data model like :

```
type Person {
  name: String!
  bio: String
  affiliation: String
  id: ID!
  photo: Photo
  sessions(filter: SessionFilter): SessionList!
}
```

> With GraphQL, you model your business domain as a graph
>
> Graphs are powerful tools for modeling many real-world phenomena because they resemble our natural mental models and verbal descriptions of the underlying process. With GraphQL, you model your business domain as a graph by defining a schema; within your schema, you define different types of nodes and how they connect/relate to one another. On the client, this creates a pattern similar to Object-Oriented Programming: types that reference other types

You can read more in the [official docucmentation](https://graphql.org/learn/thinking-in-graphs/)